# cannot put msSQL column names into array

Tags: php

I'm trying to put the column names of a msSQL table into an array. Using

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_fields($result); ++$i) {
    echo mssql_field_name($result) . "<br><br>";
}
```

the column names print to the screen just fine. Also `get_type()` shows that they are strings. However, when I try to put them into an array like this:

```
$column_names = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_fields($result); ++$i) {
     $current_column = mssql_field_name($result);
     array_push($column_names, $current_column);
}
```

`var_dump($column_names);` gives me an array (albeit the expected length) of boolean values. All false. I would expect to see an array containing the names of all my columns. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `$i` argument on the `mssql_field_name` call.  Try this maybe:

```
$column_names = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_fields($result); ++$i) {
    $column_names[] = mssql_field_name($result, $i);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-field-name.php